# List of us city mayors by year

Tags: usa, government

A similar unanswered question, [City mayor/council racial demographics](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10974/city-mayor-council-racial-demographics), prompts this more generic question.

Where can I find open data source that lists all us mayors by year?